# How can I delete duplicated records referenced as foreign keys in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation in SQL Server where I have duplicate data but in a table referenced as foreign key. The tables looks like:

- Template (id, name, description, author)
- TemplatesToAttachements (id, templateId, attachmentId)
- Attachment (id, description, author, purpose)

What I've noticed was that I have duplicated `Attachments` for a `Template`. Looking in the database, due to a bug, I've seen multiple `TemplatesToAttachements` records added for duplicated `Attachments` for the same `Template`.

Sample:

Can someone help me delete those extra `TemplatesToAttachements` records that have duplicated `Attachments` (by duplicate Attachment I mean 2 attachments that have the same description, author and purpose).

I wrote a sample of the tables here:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ef0a0

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
DELETE TemplatesToAttachements
FROM (
    SELECT Rn = ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY description, author, purpose ORDER BY id),
           id
    FROM Attachment     
) AS A
INNER JOIN TemplatesToAttachements ON TemplatesToAttachements.attachmentId = A.Id
WHERE Rn > 1
```

Comment: I can't delete from Attachment while they are referenced on TemplatesToAttachements.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() not ROW_NUMBER.  Wont work because there will be a FK error in TemplatesToAttachments.  You would need to update the new reference.

Comment: would need to do ALTER TABLE table_name NOCHECK CONSTRAINT fk_name; run the delete. run updates. reenable contraints.

Comment: This version deletes the TemplatesToAttachements but do not delete the Attachments. Thanks for help.